# Can I expand glob in context of a macro?

Tags: bazel

let's say that I want to generate multiple rules in a macro based on repository contents - something like:

```
def mymacro(dests) :
    for d in dests:
        myrule(name = d, ...)


# in a BUILD:
mymacro(dests = glob(["some/pkg/path/**"]))
```

So far, I've always gotten an empty list when I try this (although the path has many entries). Is such a thing possible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using glob like that should work fine. Glob also works within a macro (though you have to do `native.glob(...)`)

The glob pattern is probably just not matching anything. Glob will happily return an empty list if the pattern matches nothing (you can pass `allow_empty=False` to change that behavior).

Note that glob will not traverse into subpackages. So with your example `some/pkg/path/**`, if there's a build file in one of the subdirectories (`some/BUILD`, `some/pkg/BUILD`, `some/pkg/path/BUILD`, etc) then glob won't looking for anything in that subdirectory. To make files visible from one package to another, typically you'll have a `filegroup` (maybe with its own glob) in one package that another package depends on.

Comment: this is exactly correct - the glob works. I was confused because it was trying to access files that were in a subpackage and thus hidden, but as long as you are globbing files that are part of the current package, it does indeed work.